# plsql query to count between conditon and different months

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query to count transaction  made between last 3 ,6,9,12 month and amount should be between 100 - 500 then 501 - 1000 then 1001 to 2000.
simple and effective way to write .

for 3 month

```
Select Count(Transactionid),
       Customerid 
From TransactionTable where
 Transactiondate Between To_Char(Add_Months(Sysdate ,-3), 'dd-MON-yy') 
And To_Char(Sysdate, 'dd-MON-yy' ) 
and transaction_value between 100 and 500
 GROUP BY Customerid
```

This way it goes multiple time easiest way i want

Answer (score 0):

This should handle the logic you described. I have declared each set of variables as an array that can then be looped through for the result.

```
declare
    type mth_nbr is table of number;
    type range_start is table of number;
    type range_end is table of number;
    l_mth_nbr mth_nbr := mth_nbr(3,6,9,12);
    l_range_start range_start := range_start(100,501,1001,2001);
    l_range_end range_end := range_end(500,1000,2000,3000);
    l_cnt number := l_mth_nbr.count;
begin
    for i in 1..l_cnt
    loop
        select count(transactionid),
                    customerid 
        from transactiontable
        where transactiondate between to_char(Add_Months(Sysdate, -l_mth_nbr(i)),'dd-MON-yy') and to_char(sysdate, 'dd-MON-yy')
        and transaction_value between l_range_start(i) and l_range_end(i)
        group by customerid;
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're not really storing transaction date as a character, but as a date.

In which case you should be using logic along the lines of:

```
transaction date between date1 and date1
```

... not ...

```
transaction date between string1 and string2
```

So:

```
transactiondate between Add_Months(Sysdate, -l_mth_nbr(i)) and sysdate
```